# Is it possible to read the instruction pointer of a thread without stopping the tracee?

Tags: linux, profiling

I am considering writing an application-specific sampling based profiler on linux. The ptrace API, if I understand the man page correctly, relies on instrumentation in the kernel that stops the tracee whenever certain events happen in the kernel.

Is there a way to read the instruction pointer of a thread (from another thread on another core) without stopping the process?

Answer (score 0):

First, the instruction pointer alone is useless for profiling, no matter how application-specific.
Look at the second answer on [*this post*](http://archive.is/9r927) for a discussion of all the related issues.

Second, to get any useful information out of a thread, you *do* have to stop it long enough to read the information, and then it can start up again.
(Notice, this is what happens whenever it answers an interrupt of any kind.)

Don't think you need a large number of samples (or that your sampling has to be fast for that reason).
That's a long-running widely accepted idea (and taught, by people who should know better), and it is without foundation, statistical or otherwise.
(Academics might want to [*look here*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262).)

Third, take a look at [*lsstack*](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lsstack/).
If you want to write your own profiler, it would be a good code base to start from.